# CLI or ncurses tool for browsing local network?

Tags: networking, command-line, ncurses

I have a console-only SSH-based pivot box inside a remote location.  I want a console or ncurses-based tool that shows me active real-time information on which hosts are up.  IP, hostname, etc.  Something like this must exist?

This is NOT for SMB/Samba shares.  I am NOT looking for shared folders or resources.  I want a local, real-time list of all hostnames and IP addresses on the local network (maybe other info if available).

Comment: `nmap` is the linux port/os detection tool, has a very comprehensive manual page `man nmap` and many examples on the web.

Comment: I use nmap every day but it does not help with my question.

Comment: You might look at [`iftop`](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) or `netstat -c` to print continuous network info. I also researched `ntop`, `ntopng` and `sntop`, but didn't really get them running on my machine.